# Redirect TLD based on user Country

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, cloudflare

I do not believe this will be possible with .htaccess. I have multiple domains:

```
domain.mx
domain.com
domain.ca
```

I would like to force the localized TLD based on user location. IF user is from Mexico, and accesses domain.com/test/a/ they will be directed to domain.mx/test/a on first visit. From there, the website will automatically keep the user in .mx

This is my current solution in PHP, but I am not sure if Rewriting rules would be possible or faster:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_callback' );
function my_callback() {
 $userCountry = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
 $baseurl = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
 $url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
 
          // Mexico
     if (($userCountry == "MX") && (strpos($baseurl, 'mx') == false)) {
     $newurl = "https://domain.mx" . $url;
     wp_redirect( $newurl, 301 );
     exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on: https://serverfault.com/questions/357716/can-apache-conditionally-perform-a-rewrite-from-a-custom-http-header

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} = MX
RewriteRule .* https://domain.mx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

But also consider that the user may *intentionally* be trying to visit a site that does not match their location, eg: a spanish-speaking user in Canada. I would suggest allowing the user to set their desired locale, store that preference in a cookie, and use `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` to control the rewrite behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have adjusted the code correctly to ^MX$, however this is still throwing the site into a redirect loop

Comment: We need to add some sort of "Check" to make sure that .mx is not already in the domain.

Comment: CORRECT ANSWER:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^MX$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.mx
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.mx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]